# How can I insert multiple values using a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

Here is my code:

```
$post_id = 10;
$tags_id = [23, 55, 155, 15];

$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO post_tags  (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$post_id, $tags_id[0]]);
if ( !$stmt->rowCount() ){
    throwErrorMessage("Something went wrong while inserting tags");
}
```

As you can see, my code only inserts one row. I can count the number of `count($tags_id)` and copy-paste the whole code according to that number. But that approach doesn't seem good to me. Any idea what's the best approach to use an loop on that?

Answer (score 4):

Prepare **once** and insert in a loop:

```
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO post_tags  (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
foreach ($tags_id as $tag) {
    $stmt->execute([$post_id, $tag]);
    if ( !$stmt->rowCount() ){
        throwErrorMessage("Something went wrong while inserting tag " . $tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: And they are __wrong__. Prepared statements can be prepared __once__ and used many times, that is the profit.

Comment: @MartinAJ yes, that should be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can either…

**A)** use a single statement and produce the `VALUES (…)` part in side a loop.

```
$values = [];
foreach ($tags_id as $tag) {
    $values[] = sprintf( '(%d, %s)', (int)$post_id, $dbh_conn->quote($tag) );
}

$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare(
    sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO post_tags  (post_id, tag_id) VALUES %s;',
        implode(',', $values)
    ));

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    // something went wrong
}
```

or

**B)** re-use the statement for one row per `INSERT` and call the execute inside a loop. (as suggested in the other answers)

Comment: Thank you, how can I generate `values()` part dynamically?

Comment: @MartinAJ added quick example

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the insert query and execute once. Try below code, it might be help

```
$post_id = 10;
$tags_id = [23, 55, 155, 15];
$lastElement = end($tags_id);
$insert = "INSERT INTO post_tags  (post_id, tag_id) VALUES";
foreach ($tags_id as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($value == $lastElement) {
        $insert .= "(".$post_id.", ".$value.")";
    } else {
        $insert .= "(".$post_id.", ".$value."),";
    }        
}
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare($insert);
$stmt->execute();
if ( !$stmt->rowCount() ){
    throwErrorMessage("Something went wrong while inserting tags");
}
```

Comment: Such a mess of prepared statements and direct concatenation, please don't do that.

Comment: Seems complex, but the logic is fine, thank you, upvote